# Botón de consulta en BBDD de excel con VBA

Tags: base-de-datos, excel, vba, sql, macros

estoy haciendo una base de datos en excel y utilizando VBA pero no logro hacer el código para que funcione. La idea es que al escribir un dato en un textbox y presionar el botón de consulta, busque la coincidencia en cierta columna de la base de datos y arrastre los datos restantes de la fila. Añado imágenes de muestra. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El formato de la base es el siguiente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco la ayuda de antemano!

```
Sub Registrar() 
If Range("C3").Value = Empty Or Range("C5").Value = Empty Or Range("C7").Value = Empty Or Range("C9").Value = Empty then 
MsgBox ("Faltan capturar datos") 
Exit Sub     
End If 

'Fecha de alta 
Range("C3").Copy Sheets("Base de proveedores").Select
Range("A6").PasteSpecial Sheets("Registro").Select
    
End sub
```

Comment: Saludos Valentina, bienvenida, aqui te dejo una lectura altamente recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Y cual es el problema con el que te estas topando?

Comment: Con COINCIDIR podrías localizar el nº de fila que contiene los datos que te interesan, y luego ya llevarlos a tus textbox

Comment: Gracias, por la lectura, Fredy.

Comment: Pablochaches estoy aprendiendo y no encuentro cómo iniciar el código para la búsqueda de datos, entiendo que para la extracción de datos, podría ser con .copy. Esta es parte del código que hice para capturar, la lógica me dice que sería el mismo criterio, pero no logro encontrar cómo. 
Sub Registrar()
If Range("C3").Value = Empty Or Range("C5").Value = Empty Or Range("C7").Value = Empty Or Range("C9").Value = Empty 
MsgBox ("Faltan capturar datos")
Exit Sub
End If

'Fecha de alta
Range("C3").Copy
Sheets("Base de proveedores").Select
Range("A6").PasteSpecial
Sheets("Registro").Select

Comment: @ValentinaGarcía Bienvenidx a SOes. Por favor, procura que la información adicional a tu pregunta, esté en tu pregunta. Puedes editarla haciendo clic en el enlace editar que está justo bajo las etiquetas. Ya habrás visto que el código en los comentarios es difícil de seguir.

Answer (score 0):

Te comparto lo que haría para conseguir la información a grandes rasgos:

1.- Necesitas corroborar el número de filas que tiene tu base de datos yo usaría un

```
Dim Filas As Integer
Filas = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
```

2.- Utilizar un cíclico para comparar fila por fila si el valor que escribieron en tu textbox se encuentra en a base de datos y en que fila está la coincidencia.

3.- Con la fila identificada puedes copiar y pegar los valores en de cada columna en las celdas que requieres o mandar un mensaje de no coincidencia si no existe el valor buscado.

Espero estas pautas te sean útiles si requieres más ayuda de como hacer esto a detalle avísame y lo revisamos.